# I have a lot of broken Homebrew symlinks, what do I do?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, symlink

I installed `node` through homebrew 8 months ago.

- I just tried to upgrade node through homebrew and it didnt work.
- Instead, I got some message that encouraged me to run a line of code to fix it (I forget the code) but I think it broke my npm instead because my npm stopped working and I now get the error: `zsh: command not found: npm` when running any npm command.
- I proceeded to completely uninstall node with [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/6728336)
- I then began to reinstall node through homebrew with [this guide](https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x)
- When I ran brew doctor I found that I have a lot of broken `symlinks`, including many npm files such as:

  /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-README.1

  /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-access.1

  /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-adduser.1

  (along with about 60 other npm files and other fils including):

  /usr/local/bin/grunt

  /usr/local/bin/gulp

Where do I go from here?  I simply want to reinstall `node` and `npm` through homebrew so that they work properly.  Should I remove the broken symlinks with `brew prune:` or will that cause more problems for me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`brew prune` is meant for this. You can also dry run it to see what will be removed with the `--dry-run` flag.

```
prune [--dry-run]
              Remove dead symlinks from the Homebrew prefix. This is generally not needed, but can be useful when doing DIY installations. Also remove broken  app
              symlinks from /Applications and ~/Applications that were previously created by brew linkapps.

              If --dry-run or -n is passed, show what would be removed, but do not actually remove anything.
```

Comment: Works!  Thank you for saving my life

Comment: Note that as of today `brew prune` is deprecated; it’s included in `brew cleanup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up here because on the other way around you have a package installed with `brew` whose link seemed to disappear, relink like this:

```
brew unlink [package] && brew link [package]
```